# i am sure that the password and the email are correct , however the magento reports that they are invaild (aramex method)

Tags: magento, magento2

Aramex: ERR01 - ClientInfo - Invalid username or password ******* Aramex: REQ12 - DestinationAddress - City/Zipcode is empty ******* Aramex: ERR23 - ShipmentDetails.ActualWeight.Value - Value is less than zero *******

Comment: did u find a solution for this?